# Pattern for field change track in business entities

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Iam doing on some business staff for renting offices etc. One req from customer was that the product should be able to track changes in properties for specific entities (f.e. BusinessName property in Tenant class). I come up with a solution that there will be an decorator classes for every property. There will be a date when the "change was noticed" so based on that date i would like to wrap up original Tenant:ITenant class with f.e BusinessNameDecorator:TenantDecorator:ITenant class.

Raw solution is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbAsi.png)

The problem for that is that the code starts to smell and plumbing get to business classes. Is there any proved and verified solution or pattern for tracking changes and persisting them in business entities? I dont want to reinvent the wheel but unfortunately i did not found anything.

Thank you for your help
P.S.: Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting up a mechanism like EF's POCO support. When you use POCOs with Entity Framework, EF still manages to track which properties have changed on your entity objects.

Basically EF uses Reflection.Emit to create at runtime classes that derive from your POCOs and add the change tracking behavior (provided that the tracked properties of your POCOs are declared as virtual).

It can be really complicated to achieve this, but if you have to apply the mechanism to a large number of classes it's probably well worth it.